# "Can not mount /dev/loop0" during install from CD

Tags: system-installation

Whenever I boot up my PC from the CD, it starts shows the Ubuntu logo with the loading sign and then gives me this error:

`Can not mount /dev/loop0(/cdrom/casper/filesystem/squashfs) om //filesystem squashfs`

I tried downloading and burning the ISO again but I got the same problem. I also tried using a Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx CD but it shows the same error too.
It happens on 2 PCs, one with 512 MB RAM and the other with 2 GB RAM. The same CD works flawlessly on my laptop.

Error while installing Ubuntu from CD "Can not mount /dev/loop0(/cdrom/casper/filesystem/squashfs) om //filesystem squashfs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer may not have enough RAM to use the Desktop CD. Try installing with the Alternate CD and see if you have any better success.

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Also you might want to double check the CD image has downloaded properly:

- [Unable to mount /dev/loop0 during install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5996/unable-to-mount-dev-loop0-during-install)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when my `.iso` file was missing some bits. Redownloading and mounting it again solved it for me.

Comment: I used the same iso for two computers. It worked flawlessly on one but gave this error on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Guys it seems that this issue has more to do with what kind of drive your packing than not enough free space, i have found that an easy way to solve this problem is to download the ubuntu 10.10(it does not have to be this verison, this just happens to be the latest one) dvd version. These "**DVD Versions**" tend to be 4GB in size as appose to the regular 690-700mb ISO File. Please tell me if this has also solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when installing 10.10 64 bit from CD-R. I then burned the same iso image to dvd-r and also changed bios plug-and-play option from off to on - error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing from the host system instead of from a CD or DVD - VMware 8 gives you the option of installing the guest operating system from an iso located somewhere on the host operating system. I'm running vmware on Windows 7 and located the ubuntu 10.4 iso in the MyDocuments folder on Windows. Ubuntu installed under VMWare with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Burning to a DVD instead of a CD solved this. The CD was supposed to be big enough if you look at the sizes, but it never worked for me.