# booting with liveCD not working saying that it can not mount /dev/loop0

Tags: boot

I wanted to try Ubuntu so I was going to partition my hard drive so I restart my computer with my live CD in the disc drive

when it boots it shows the typical booting screen for about ten minutes then the screen goes to text only and says that it can't mount/dev/loop0
first I type

> help

then I type

> mount /dev/loop0

then it says fstab cannot be found

and I don't know were to go from there

I have seen numerous times that it could be a ram problem

I am not someone who knows much about memory so this is a snippet from my dell inspiron 8500

> Memory

Memory module connector two user-accessible SODIMM sockets
Memory module capacities 256 MB, 512 MB, and 1024 MB
Memory type 266-MHz DDR SDRAM
Standard memory 256 MB
Maximum memory 2 GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen when you have a bad CD image (or you don't have enough RAM to run the installer), check the answers to these questions and see if they help:

- ["Can not mount /dev/loop0" during install from CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6171/can-not-mount-dev-loop0-during-install-from-cd)
- [Unable to mount /dev/loop0 during install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5996/unable-to-mount-dev-loop0-during-install)

If you don't have enough RAM for the desktop installer try the [alternate installer CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).

Comment: this is actually my second cd I thought I had a bad image so I downloaded another one and burned to another cd

Comment: it is very possible that I don't have enough RAM I have a very small not-a-lot-of-memory computer