# Not able to install Ubuntu 'Can not mount /dev/loop0'

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to mount /dev/loop0 during install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5996/unable-to-mount-dev-loop0-during-install)

I am try to install Ubuntu 10.10 download from http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/alternative-download.
ISO image burnt to a CD and i boot from this cd. But i am not able to install because of some error 'Input/Output error Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs'

So please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: What program are you using to burn the cd? What version of Ubuntu are you using right now?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe CD is damaged? Try to boot ISO image on VirtualBox. If it works, CD media is probably damaged. Possible reason might be that your CD/DVD drive is dirty or broken.
If you cannot boot ISO image in VirtualBox, downloaded ISO image might be corrupted. In this case, try to calculate checksum of ISO image, and compare to md5 checksum on ubuntu page where you downloaded your ISO image.