# 'Can not mount /dev/loop0' fault during installation CD booting

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to mount /dev/loop0 during install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5996/unable-to-mount-dev-loop0-during-install)

I have currently WindowsXP installed in my computer.

I burned Ubuntu 10.04 into a CD and then inserted the CD into the drive and booted.

When the CD boots I get to a terminal screen that outputs:

```
BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/ccasper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

How do I deal with this?