# Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs)

Tags: boot, squashfs

I downloaded 12.04.1 and md5 sum checked them and everything is good.

Made a live usb and booted up...

Just gets to where its about to start with the purple ubuntu loading screen then it goes back to text and gives this message:

> BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash) Enter
>   'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on ///filesystem.squashfs
>   failed: Input/output error Can not mount /dev/loop0
>   (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs

This happens in the live option, or persistent even the file checking one doesn't work

Also I've tried a few different <kbd>F6</kbd> options to no avail.

I used 'LiLi USB creator' and 'unetbootin' and also 'Universal USB Installer,' all with the same results. I've also tried using a VM and it showed the same. That is when I figured I had a corrupt .iso so I downloaded it again checked the MD5: e235b63c02644e219b7bf3668f479c9e. Only I'm having the same problem.

I'm just about ready to give up on 12.04.1 and just go back to 10.04 utill the next LTS comes out.

I've got a dell mini 10 btw.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer may not have enough RAM to use the Desktop CD. Try installing with the Alternate CD

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Also you might want to double check the CD image has downloaded properly:

[Unable to mount /dev/loop0 during install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5996/unable-to-mount-dev-loop0-during-install)

Comment: It downloaded right and I've got 2GB of ram, I think that should be enough.

Comment: Have you made memory test?!

Comment: Let me do that real quick. Weird thing is it does it on VM too.

Comment: It's quite unclear why! All of what i found for your problem the above solutions

Comment: I know, I usually just look at what other people did for the same problem. This is the first time I couldn't find a solution from the forums.

Comment: anyway what is result of the memory test?!

Comment: Its still going, no errors yet. I guess its only got 1 GB of ram. So maybe it is that.

Comment: its probably a memory issue

Comment: Just passes Memtest with no problems. Also I was using this computer until just a little while ago with no problems running on 10.04. I had to repair it so while I was working on it I booted the hard drive through an external enclosure and it messed up something because now it won't find where the OS is. That's why I'm trying to do a new install. I'm going to try the alternate CD and see if that works.

Comment: Just got the VM to boot.

Comment: I'm remaking the live usb in the vitual box using ubuntu's built-in tool.

Comment: good it should do the job

Comment: Looks like it works. That is really weird because all the usb creators programs (LiLi usb crator, Unetbootin, Universal usb creator) said 12.04 on them, it has been out since April so I would expect them to be compatible by now. By the way, Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are very welcomed please mark as accepted answer and upvote if this helped you for other users to get help from