# Check Disk Defects: Can not mount /dev/loop0

Tags: boot, system-installation

I use `Universal USB Installer` and `Ubuntu 14.04.1.desktop.iso` to install Ubuntu to my laptop(already installed win7). And when I enter `Install Ubuntu`, it reports

```
(initramfs) mount: mounting dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Input/Output error Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

just like this: [Unable to mount /dev/loop0 during install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5996/unable-to-mount-dev-loop0-during-install)

Then I run `Check Defects`, it is the same. I checked the ISO's MD5, it is correct.

How can I fixed it?

Comment: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

If the checksum is correct and the check for defects come out fine, **try another USB stick first!**  If that still fails, try a CD.

If all that fails as well, you should  file a bug [here](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+filebug), following [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingCasper) and attach the `/casper.log` from your USB stick to it.